# Mongoose Cast to ObjectId failed for value "xxx" at path "_id"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I´m trying to get some files using a restriction where

```
ShipmentRequest.find()
      .where('estatus').in(['Asignada','Inicio Carga','Fin Carga','En Transito','Entregada'])
      .exec(function(err,solicitudes){
        if(err){
          return res.status(400).json({message:'Error, no se pudieron obtener las solicitudes',error:err});
        }
        else {
          return res.status(200).json(solicitudes);
        }
    });
```

but I get this error

```
Cast to ObjectId failed for value "estatus" at path "_id"
```

I already used the same "where" restriction at the same collection with no errors so I don't understand why I'm getting it here.

Comment: How looks `ShipmentRequest` model schema?

Comment: There was no problem with the schema, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was that there were a conflict between two routes, and the fist one asked for an `_id` and the second for an `status` so I've changed the second one to avoid the conflict and it worked.